# Set image on imageview from url resources

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have `image` with [url](https://graph.facebook.com/10204810015761944/picture?type=square).

How can I assign this resource to an `imageview` inside my app?

Answer (score 1):

Check this Picasso library and it very easy to load image url on imageview
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
URL url = new URL("http://yourURL.com/...");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use picasso,
for example

Add this line in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and you code :

```
       ImageView horario = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);


Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(horario);
```

[Documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/)